# realizar array_push de un array hacia otro

Tags: php, php7, php8

Tengo 2 `arrays` diferentes y necesito agregar datos de un array a otro. Se me ocurre iterando con un `for` sobre el primero y con `array_push` pero no he podido.

```
Array1 ( 
[0] => 2022-11-06
[1] => 2022-11-07 
)

Array2 ( 
[0] => Array ( [hora] => 08:00 [id] => 27 ) 
[1] => Array ( [hora] => 09:00 [id] => 27 ) 
)

Array que debe quedar ( 
[0] => Array ( [hora] => 08:00 [id] => 27 [0]=> 2022-11-06) 
[1] => Array ( [hora] => 09:00 [id] => 27 [0]=> 2022-11-06) 
[2] => Array ( [hora] => 08:00 [id] => 27 [1] => 2022-11-07) 
[3] => Array ( [hora] => 09:00 [id] => 27 [1] => 2022-11-07) 
 
)
```

Todo sea bienvenido, ¿Algún punto de partida?

Muchas gracias!

Resuelta, dejo código por si alguien le sirve:

```
$array1 = array(
0 => "2022-11-06",
1 => "2022-11-07",
);
$length = sizeof($array1);
$array2 = array(
0 => array( "hora" => "08:00", "id" => 27 ),
1 => array( "hora" => "09:00", "id" => 27 ),
);
$num = 0;
$array3 = array ();
for ($i=0;$i<sizeof($array2);$i++){
    for ($j=0;$j<$length;$j++){
    array_push($array3,$array2[$i]);
    array_push($array3[$num],$array1[$j]);
    $num = $num+1;
    }
}

$arr = array_slice($array3,0,-$length);
```

Comment: Agrega el código que has intentado en el `array_push` y el error o el porqué no se ha podido.

Comment: El método de fusión no es para nada intuitivo. ¿Qué deseas conseguir exactamente?¿un producto cartesiano entre cada fila del segundo array con el primero?¿El identificador para tu segundo array es la hora? del contrario, ¿Por qué dos bloques horarios tienen el mismo id?